# How to Test sort functionality of a list in appium?

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a list view with list of names displaying in ascending order.
Example: 
01_AutoName_abcde
01_AutoName_fgh
01_AutoName_ijkl
01_AutoName_mnop

Now, using Appium i want to test whether this list view is sorted by default with names.Can anyone please help me with a piece of code for this ?

Comment: you can use linkedHashSet which sort data bydefault
http://iforerunner.com/sunjava/posts/list/117.page;jsessionid=35FECE7BA632EE572CF10AAF17C5D8F8#.VtUooHWlykr

Comment: Do findElements() with relevant locator so that all the elements are stored in a List. Get text for all the elements and store in another String List. You can use Collections.sort() to sort all the names manually and correspondingly you can compare it with the default ordering of elements.

Comment: @nullpointer Yes. of course I know, this isn't a great approach.. but at least easy to understand and straight forward (or a kind of Layman approach), that is the reason I didn't post this in the answer section. You may go ahead and add a better solution. :)

Comment: Not for you in any way Prateek, message for veerendra there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions.please keep posted with any new ideas for this question